# Computer stops booting every month

Tags: windows-10, boot, bsod, crash

Every one or two months, my computer goes through the following:

- Crashes on startup (and will crash on any future startup attempt. This has been a BSoD or just freezing in the windows logo).
- Startup repair causes the computer to restart and crash.
- System restore results in an unknown error.
- Starting in safe mode BSoDs with "machine check exception".

This occurs after no changes to the computer (i.e. not after new hardware or a software update). It just happens. The CPU is not overclocked and when monitoring temperatures, nothing appears to be overheating. The only way to make the computer usable again is to reinstall windows, which is inconvenient.

How can I diagnose the issue? The SSD the OS is on is new and the RAM has been fairly recently tested. Could it be the CPU, and if so, how could I test it? GPU?

Comment: Check your windows event logs for red errors. You can also post your dump files from the BSOD. Once that information is available you can dig deeper for an answer.

Comment: Once this happens I cannot boot up the computer again to access any logs.

Comment: try to boot from a Linux Live CD/DVD and get the dmp files from Windows\Minidump

Comment: were you able to get the dumps?